# Solr metadata index

Tags: solr, solr-cell

I am new with Solr and I am extracting metadata from binary files through URLs stored in my database.  I would like to know what fields are available for indexing from PDFs (the ones that would be initiated as column=””).  I would also like to know how to create customized fields in Solr.  How is that implemented and mapped to specific metadata coming from the files.  If someone has a code snippet that could show me it would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To create custom fields in Solr, you will need to modify the `schema.xml` file for your Solr installation. The [schema.xml](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/lucene/dev/branches/lucene_solr_4_2/solr/example/solr/collection1/conf/schema.xml?view=markup) file that comes with the Solr example included in the distribution (found under the /example folder) includes a large number of predefined metadata fields for file extraction. For information on creating custom fields in Solr, please see the following:

- [SchemaXml](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml)
- [Documents, Fields & Schema Design](http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/Documents,+Fields,+and+Schema+Design)

Solr has a built in request handler for extracting and mapping metadata from binary files. For details, please referer to the following:

- [ExtractingRequestHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler)
- [Uploading Data with Solr Cell using Apache Tika](http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/Uploading+Data+with+Solr+Cell+using+Apache+Tika)

Comment: Hi Paige, thanks a lot for your answer.  I want to be able to index without using the curl command.  My code is set to index dynamically.  Could you please give me an example of how would I extract something like the file size, format or file type?  What would be the column names that would relate to those types of fields?  Also, I am wondering if you have a little code snippet of how to map custom fields.  Do I have to declare that in the solrconfig.xml or do some more tweaking somewhere else?

Comment: For a code example, please see this link from the Solr wiki - http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ContentStreamUpdateRequestExample As for the column names, please refer to the example and adjust settings accordingly in the schema.xml using the links above as reference.